# Android "setColorFilter may produce NullPointerException" caution disappears

Tags: android, android-studio, nullpointerexception, android-tablayout, colorfilter

I am developing simple application that has TabLayout. Each tab has its own icon drawable. When tab is active, its icon should be in white color, otherwise it should have darker color. Now when I write this code:

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.colorIcons), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.colorDivider), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
```

Android studio gives me a caution about NullPointerException:
[image: SetColorFilter may produce NullPointerException]

However, when I extract this to separate method, everything is okay and Android Studio doesn't complain:

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                setIconColor(tab.getIcon(), true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                setIconColor(tab.getIcon(), false);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
```

this new method:

```
private void setIconColor(Drawable icon, boolean active){
        if (active) {
            icon.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.colorIcons), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        } else {
            icon.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.colorDivider), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        }
    }
```

It feels strange that after sending functionality to separate method it no longer complains that method invocation may produce NullPointerException. Am I missing something or it's a bad behavior of Android studio?

Answer (score 2):

You see this warning because the `getIcon()` method in `TabLayout` has the [`@Nullable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/Nullable.html) annotation. To see it, you can either view the source code for the method in your IDE (I believe by doing shift+click), or search for the method [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.java).

In any case, the purpose of this annotation is exactly so you as a developer are made aware of the fact that this method may return `null`, and as such you may want to plan for such cases in your application logic. Otherwise, if you attempt to call `setColorFilter()` when `getIcon()` returns `null`, you will crash with a `NullPointerException`